# consumir un web service con C#, utilizando Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, webservice

Tengo una pagina web del lado cliente que funciona con Javascript para mostrar información, pero quiero consumir un web service para que el usuario pueda interactuar con dicha pagina y no solo consultar de esta, el problema es que el web service solo puede ser consumido con lenguajes .NET (C++, C#, F# y VB).

Me gustaría conocer la forma  o saber si es posible crear la conexión al servicio web desde C#,y utilizando Javascript para pasarle los parámetros y ejecutar así los métodos contenidos en C#.

(El servicio web que quiero consumir es el Master Data Manager de Microsoft)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Lo que podrias hacer es crear un [Web Api en c#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) que sea el *intermediario entre tu aplicacion web y tu servicio*.

Por ejemplo si tu servicio returna el estado de cuentas de seria asi:

```
public class CuentasController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpResponseMessage ObtenerEstadoCuenta(int clienteid)
    {
       var estadosCuentaServicio = new EstadoCuentaServicio();

       return Ok(estadosCuentaServicio.ObtenerEstadosCuentaClient(clienteId);
   }
}
```

Entonces para obtener los datos desde javascript con jquery seria:

```
$.get("http://nombre_aplicacion/api/cuentas/obtenerestadocuenta?clientid=2", function(estados){
  // procesas los estados
});
```

[La web tiene muchos tutoriales](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1tc_HUGL7iM) que pudieras dar le una miradita.